# Realloc corruption after some iteration C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc, memory-corruption

I'm trying to dynamically allocate memory for an array of struct pointer in function. It works until 3 iteration but crash after with this error :

```
double free or corruption (fasttop): ...
```

Here is my struct pointer array declaration :

```
Intersection** alreadyUse = malloc(sizeof(Intersection*));

if(alreadyUse == NULL) {
   exit(1);
}

int size = 1;
alreadyUse[0] = inter; // Pointer of an Intersection

// Some Code

checkFunction(alreadyUse, &size, interLeft);
```

And this is my function

```
bool checkFunction(Intersection** alreadyUse, int* size, Intersection* inter) {

    for(int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        if(alreadyUse[i] == inter) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    *size = *size +1;
    Intersection** tmp = realloc(alreadyUse, sizeof(Intersection*) * *size);

    if(tmp == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        alreadyUse = tmp;
    }

    alreadyUse[*size-1] = inter;

    return false;
}
```

As I said, it works for 1, 2, 3 then I get the error.

Is someone have an idea why it works and then suddenly crash ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: We don't know the Intersection type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function call

```
checkFunction(alreadyUse, &size, interLeft);
```

the variable `size` is passed by reference. So it can be changed in the function. However as you see the variable `alreadyUse`  is not passed by reference. So the function deals with a copy of the value of the variable. If you want that the variable would be changed in the function you have to pass it by reference

```
checkFunction( &alreadyUse, &size, interLeft);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thus the function should be declared like

```
bool checkFunction(Intersection*** alreadyUse, int* size, Intersection* inter);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The function definition can look like

```
bool checkFunction( Intersection ***alreadyUse, int *size, Intersection *inter ) 
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < *size; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( alreadyUse[0][i] == inter ) return true;
    }

    Intersection **tmp = realloc( alreadyUse[0], sizeof( Intersection * ) * ( *size + 1 ) );

    if ( tmp == NULL ) exit( 1 );

    alreadyUse[0] = tmp;

    alreadyUse[0][( *size )++] = inter;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Saying `size` is passed "by reference" is confusing and inaccurate since C is a purely pass by value language. A pointer to `size` is passed by value.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The term by reference is valid and accurate in C For example "A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type".

Comment: Perhaps: "... a _reference_ to `size` is passed ..."

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you ! It works.

I thought the pointers were passed by reference, but obviously I was wrong.

Comment: @David Schwartz: "Passing by reference" is a well-established language-independent concept. Its meaning is well-understood in the context of C language and it is widely used in that context. Everybody knowns that "passing something by reference" (or, sometimes "passing something by pointer") is just another (shorter) way of saying "passing a pointer to something by value".

Comment: @Michael Dorgan I can reverse an integer array and even know the C++ Standard algorithm std::reverse.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Your purported example doesn't use the phrase "by reference" or "pass by reference", so it doesn't show that the phrase "by reference" is valid or accurate. And, I would add, this conflicts with the most upvoted answer defining what [pass by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/721269) means which also explains how I learned the term, have always used the term, and have always heard the term used.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The answer in the given reference is just incorrect. The answerer does not know C.:) For example this phrase "When a parameter is passed by reference, the caller and the callee use the same variable for the parameter" does not make sense. For example parameters are not passed to functions.:) And parameters are local variables of functions. Thus the caller and the callee do not use the same variable.:)

Answer (score 4):

You change the value of `alreadyUse` inside `checkFunction`. But this has no effect on the caller. If the call to `realloc` actually reallocates, the caller still has a pointer to the old block that has now been freed.